# Codeigniter - sessions not working through controller and view

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm trying to make a login using sessions in codeigniter at the time the username and password match, but I can't get it. I'm doing this:

Controller:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('main_select');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('session');

    }

    ...code when username and password match:
if($pass === $user){
        $this->session->set_userdata(array(
                                    'user_id' => $login['id_user'],
                            ));//we create the session 'user_id'
}
```

here it is supposed that we created a session called 'user_id'
in the view it doesn't work, I have this:

```
if( !$this->session->userdata('id_user') ){
//see this content
//first content
}else{
//see this other
//second content
}
```

but I always see the same content('second content').

trying to destroy it (but not working):

```
public function logout()
    {
        //session_unset(); 
        // destroy the session 
        //session_destroy();
        $this->session->unset_userdata('id_user');      

        header("Location: ".base_url() );
    }
```

what am I doing wrong?  thanks

EDIT1:

```
$password = md5( $this->input->post('inputpassword') ); 
$login =  $this->login_select->get_username($username);

//si no coincide
if( $login['password'] !== $password ) {}
```

Comment: does `$pass` ever equal `$user`? Have you done a dump of the sesssion to see what it contains? We can't debug those steps for you

Comment: yes definitely it works that part.

Comment: so what's in the session dump?

Comment: echo var_dump($this->session->userdata('id_user') );  prints false: why?

Comment: Not sure because not enough code shown to know what `$login` is or where it comes from or if $pass and $user really are equal

Comment: I have checked out and they match, but I'm not sure why the session is not created, Do I need session_start()?

Comment: not when using CI session, they aren't a real php sesssion. Could be `$login` isn't what you think it is

Comment: i don't think so, because $login =  $this->login_select->get_username($username); I use it for store info from the database, so I have $login['username'], login['password'] etc

Comment: is it a correct way for verify if session exists: if( !$this->session->userdata('id_user') ){}

Comment: sure but the value is `false` so you need to figure out why it's `false`

Comment: also for destroying the session is this the correct way: $this->session->unset_userdata('id_user');   ?

Comment: in version 2 it is https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: yes, but for creating a new session is this the correct way: $this->session->set_userdata('user_id', 'some_value');  ??

Comment: Read the docs I just posted link to them

Comment: I did, but I can't solve this problem, thanks for replying

Comment: @user2580401 can you post code of `$pass` and `$user`, means data assign to those variables

Comment: $this->session->set_userdata(array(
                                    'user_id' => $login['id_user'],
                            ));  here you set user_id as session variable not id_user and hence $this->session->userdata('user_id');  will work instead of $this->session->userdata('id_user');

Comment: yes, check out the edit1

Comment: but, I'm sure that part is working

Answer (score 0):

**Note :** Always use database to handle user logins. (Code is related to database login check)

in your database create table with `user` and add this 2 fields.

1. username
2. password

Add some user logins to it

Then in your code

```
public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('main_select');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('session');

    }

// logging
public function loging()
{
    $user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $pass = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));

    $validate = $this->main_select->validate_user($user,$pass);

    if(empty($validate) || $validate>1)
    {
        //Not a valid user
        //redirect to login page
        $this->load->view('loging');
    }
    else
    {
        //valid user
        //set the session

        $array = array('user_id' => '$user');
        $this->session->set_userdata();
        //redirect to normal page
        $this->load->view('home_page');
    }
}

//logout
public function logout()
{

    $result= $this->session->sess_destroy(); 

    if ((isset($result))) 
    {
        header("Location: ".base_url() );
    }    
    else
    {

    }


}
```

In Model

```
public function validate_user($user,$pass)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username= '$user' AND password='$pass'");
    $result = $query->result_array();
    $count = count($result);
    return $count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

modify this line of changes then your script will work as id_user need to set first to use in script.

```
   if($pass === $login['password'] && $user===$login['username']){
              $this->session->set_userdata(array(
                                'id_user' => $login['id_user'],
                        ));//we create the session 'user_id'
  }
```

here `$login['password']`  and `$login['username']` are data come from tables and need to change fieldname pass or user according to your user table.